# Unsure why mutator function is not working

Tags: python, discord

I'm trying to make a gym discord bot and currently I have an object of a class ("Exercise") I've made stored inside of a dictionary ("push_exercises"). I have a method from the Exercise class called "change_name" that changes the name attribute of an object.

In my code, I store the key to the dictionary in a variable called "user_exercise_name" which is provided by the user. Another function already ensures that there must be that key in the dictionary when searched.

My issue is that when I call "push_exercises[user_exercise_name].change_name(user_input)", the object's name property does not change.

```
push_exercises = {}
pull_exercises = {}
leg_exercises = {}

@client.command()
async def update(ctx):
    user_exercise_name = ""
    user_choice = ""
    user_input = ""
    await ctx.send("Update from \"Push\", \"Pull\", or \"Legs\"?")

    # Checks conditions for message output
    try:
        message = await client.wait_for("message", check=lambda msg: msg.author == ctx.author and
                                                                     msg.channel == ctx.channel, timeout=30.0)

    # Timeout condition
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send("User Timed Out")

    # Checks the messages if no errors
    else:
        # Push Case
        if message.content.lower() == "push":
            await ctx.send("Enter the name of an exercise to update:")

            # Removes push exercises
            try:
                message = await client.wait_for("message",
                                                check=lambda msg:
                                                msg.author == ctx.author and
                                                msg.channel == ctx.channel,
                                                timeout=30.0)
            # Timeout condition
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                await ctx.send("User Timed Out")

            else:
                # Gets key for exercise from user to update
                user_exercise_name = message.content

                if user_exercise_name in push_exercises:

                    await ctx.send("Update \"name\", \"weight\", or \"comment\"?")

                    try:
                        message = await client.wait_for("message",
                                                        check=lambda msg:
                                                        msg.author == ctx.author and
                                                        msg.channel == ctx.channel,
                                                        timeout=30.0)
                    # Timeout condition
                    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                        await ctx.send("User Timed Out")

                    else:
                        user_choice = message.content

                        # Updates name
                        if user_choice.lower() == "name":

                            # Finds exercise to update
                            if user_exercise_name in push_exercises:
                                await ctx.send("Enter a new name for " + user_exercise_name + ": ")

                                # Removes push exercises
                                try:
                                    message = await client.wait_for("message",
                                                                    check=lambda msg:
                                                                    msg.author == ctx.author and
                                                                    msg.channel == ctx.channel,
                                                                    timeout=30.0)
                                # Timeout condition
                                except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                                    await ctx.send("User Timed Out")

                                else:
                                    user_input = message.content
                                    push_exercises[user_exercise_name].change_name(user_input)
                                    await ctx.send("Exercise name updated successfully")

                        else:
                            await ctx.send("Invalid input")
                            return
                # if user input exercise does not exist
                else:
                    await ctx.send("Exercise does not exist")
                    return
        else:
            await ctx.send("Invalid input")
            return

# Exercise Class
class Exercise:
    name = ""
    weight = 0
    comment = ""

    def __init__(self, *args):                                
        if len(args) == 1:
            self.name = args[0]
            self.weight = 0
            self.comment = ""
        elif len(args) == 2:
            self.name = args[0]
            self.weight = args[1]
            self.comment = ""
        elif len(args) == 3:
            self.name = args[0]
            self.weight = args[1]
            self.comment = args[2]

    def change_name(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def change_weight(self, weight):
        self.weight = weight

    def change_comment(self, comment):
        self.comment = comment

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_weight(self):
        return self.weight

    def get_comment(self):
        return self.comment

    def print_exercise(self):
        print("Name: " + self.name)
        print("Weight: " + str(self.weight))
        print("Comment: " + self.comment)

@client.command()
async def add(ctx):
    user_exercise_name = ""

    await ctx.send("Add to \"Push\", \"Pull\", or \"Legs\"?")

    # Checks conditions for message output
    try:
        message = await client.wait_for("message", check=lambda msg: msg.author == ctx.author and
                                                                     msg.channel == ctx.channel, timeout=30.0)

    # Timeout condition
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send("User Timed Out")

    # Checks the messages if no errors
    else:
        # Push Case
        if message.content.lower() == "push":
            await ctx.send("Enter the name of an exercise to add to push:")

            # Adds push exercises
            try:
                message = await client.wait_for("message",
                                                check=lambda msg:
                                                msg.author == ctx.author and
                                                msg.channel == ctx.channel,
                                                timeout=30.0)
            # Timeout condition
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                await ctx.send("User Timed Out")

            # Takes user_input
            else:
                # Gets user_input for exercise data and creates an object to store in dictionary
                user_exercise_name = message.content

                # If exercise exists                                (IS CASE SENSITIVE, IMPROVE LATER)
                if user_exercise_name in push_exercises:
                    await ctx.send("Duplicate exercise, please enter a new exercise")
                    return

                else:
                    push_exercises[user_exercise_name] = Exercise(user_exercise_name)

                    # Creates an exercise object to store in the dictionary
                    await ctx.send("You've added " + push_exercises[user_exercise_name].get_name() + " to push day.")

        # Pull case
        elif message.content.lower() == "pull":
            await ctx.send("Enter the name of an exercise to add to pull:")

            # Adds pull exercises
            try:
                message = await client.wait_for("message",
                                                check=lambda msg:
                                                msg.author == ctx.author and
                                                msg.channel == ctx.channel,
                                                timeout=30.0)
            # Timeout condition
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                await ctx.send("User Timed Out")

            # Takes user_input
            else:
                # Gets user_input for exercise data and creates an object to store in dictionary
                user_exercise_name = message.content

                # If exercise exists                                (IS CASE SENSITIVE, IMPROVE LATER)
                if user_exercise_name in pull_exercises:
                    await ctx.send("Duplicate exercise, please enter a new exercise")
                    return

                else:
                    pull_exercises[user_exercise_name] = Exercise(user_exercise_name)

                    # Creates an exercise object to store in the dictionary
                    await ctx.send("You've added " + pull_exercises[user_exercise_name].get_name() + " to pull day.")

        # Legs case
        elif message.content.lower() == "legs":
            await ctx.send("Enter the name of an exercise to add to legs:")

            # Adds legs exercises
            try:
                message = await client.wait_for("message",
                                                check=lambda msg:
                                                msg.author == ctx.author and
                                                msg.channel == ctx.channel,
                                                timeout=30.0)
            # Timeout condition
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                await ctx.send("User Timed Out")

            # Takes user_input
            else:
                # Gets user_input for exercise data and creates an object to store in dictionary
                user_exercise_name = message.content

                # If exercise exists                                (IS CASE SENSITIVE, IMPROVE LATER)
                if user_exercise_name in leg_exercises:
                    await ctx.send("Duplicate exercise, please enter a new exercise")
                    return

                else:
                    leg_exercises[user_exercise_name] = Exercise(user_exercise_name)

                    # Creates an exercise object to store in the dictionary
                    await ctx.send("You've added " + leg_exercises[user_exercise_name].get_name() + " to leg day.")

        else:
            await ctx.send("Invalid Input")
```

I've looked at my exercise class and my main code, printing out if the object was created, if the key worked, and if the other functions like my print function from the Exercise class worked. Everything worked, as the object was created, the dictionary could be accessed, and other functions worked. It's just the mutator function which would not change the name property of the object.

Comment: As far as I can see, this code never adds anything to `push_exercises`.  It starts as an empty dictionary and it stays that way, so `if user_exercise_name in push_exercises` is never true.

Comment: Also, I do not see any code that would try to access the `name` attribute  after it is changed.  So how do you know it was not changed?

Comment: It sounds like there is a lot of other code that you haven't shown us...

Comment: @JohnGordon I see I see thank you! I've edited the post to include the !add function. Basically when I tested this function, the dictionary did contain an object that I could run the class's print function on. Yet, the change name function did not work on the object :(